# Arithmetically random bitstreams

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, measure-theory

**Motivation (informal).** When trying to generate a random bit-stream, we expect that "half of the" bits are $0$, and the "other half" are $1$. So, how about $010101\ldots$? Well, we would also expect that if we look at every second member of the sequence, then "half of" those bits are $0$ and the other half are $1$. So, let's make this precise.

**Formal version.** Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of non-negative integers. We can identify every bit-stream, that is function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$ with some $A\in{\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$ (take $A = f^{-1}(\{1\})$).

Given any $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ we define maps $\mu_S^+, \mu_S^-:{\cal P}(\mathbb{N})\to[0,1]$ by $$\mu^{+}_S(A)= \lim \sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap S \cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|}{1+|S\cap \{1,\ldots,n\}|}, \text{ and } \mu^{-}_S(A)= \lim \inf_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap S \cap\{1,\ldots,n\}|}{1+|S\cap \{1,\ldots,n\}|}.$$

We say that $A$ is *well-balanced* with respect to $S$ if $\mu^+_S(A) = \mu^-_S(A) = 1/2$.

For $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ with $a>0$ we set $S_{a,b} = \{an+b:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and we say that $A\in{\cal P}(\mathbb{N})$ is *arithmetically random* if $A$ is well-balanced with respect to $S_{a,b}$ for any $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ with $a>0$.

What is an example of an arithmetically random set $A\in{\cal P}(\mathbb N)$?

Comment: Going by this title and motivation, it's worth pointing out a generalization: algorithmic randomness. This is one test of randomness; we can formulate other tests, and even asks for sequences that pass all such tests. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmically_random_sequence

Comment: Brilliant - thanks @usul!

Comment: You might also read Knuth's discussion of random sequences in Volume 2 of The Art Of Computer Programming, especially Chapter 3.5, What is a Random Sequence?

Comment: +1 for the neat question, though I'd suggest not seeing this notion of a sequence being well-balanced as relating to it being "_truly random_".

Comment: Thanks @nat for your comment - I changed the title to "arithmetically random".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) is such an example, as was (first, I believe) [proved by Dumont](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=725391).

If you take a uniformly random real number in $[0,1]$, its binary expansion will have this property with probability $1$; I imagine it is conjectured that the binary expansion of every algebraic irrational number has this property.

You might also be interested in the related [Erdös discrepancy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_sequence#Erd%C5%91s_discrepancy_problem).

Answer (score 3):

The Champernowne constant $C_2$  ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant )
has the  stronger property of normality (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#Properties) for properties of normal numbers. If you examine a normal number along an infinite arithmetic progression and extract the resulting digits, this is also a normal number

Comment: True, although it's interesting to note that the convergence to normality (or to well-balanced as in the OP) is extremely slow.

Answer (score 2):

Mauduit and Sarkozy have studied essentially this and other related pseudorandomness measures for finite as well as infinite $\{\pm 1\}-$valued sequences, see [here](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271536/1-s2.0-S0012365X00X04384/1-s2.0-S0012365X0300044X/main.pdf?x-amz-security-token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEHsaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQDfgy29negvXsjgJTsmT%2FZq%2FZ7qr7cvgWxVAyGG64GrXwIgD8Xwy8k6WkmDH%2BixDdtYJqXrsmigw7I5In6LhyoA9ysq4wMIpP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARACGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDN7KuzO%2FRYG5n6fYCiq3A%2BLBa7uBV3MDIkwJhTwEknDQ17nP60UxBmy74wuToB2%2FSnTNesq%2BXbX0SdrlO5xwkCdJAvXGMwxmJYc9itBMK4s63JOnfmZvFa6%2BVhYxG%2BSZQU6BM7sj9ow5SaYthKuOMI2qz2bog1fNVO0j7bo5YX6RsJnErao8E7C68j%2BjnbL0hS1c4ofFv1U6ChFxAZI1QB%2BCNs6%2BYtylb0VY0WKiogZPCudxFEIcXqhJJlv3znhg%2FynOmrJF5Iv3lg%2FfPERZJtb65caLPL%2BlMcoq9Wx2aHIUSts0XmXQTJB0%2FieA9GIoNASETGxtZLW4e%2BSoc6vLSVW2Zc2Y3TokIxpFpTdtYfAfZHGhW5aNUEtyIGJtjvfnAsC0f22w3WzGIcF3qYRWZCnfFY1jqCOEVloqqLanT96A3ZdnQN1RG1dtK%2BgssUKwNkMOEhjr7kJ1u0OMmginbOVrFjbw6KQgetmTYs3eSCAxYxRTV0AowNS5%2FVKgqywKaD%2FswcIXei7UgszSydpj3zckhm9KtwMCy0RD%2Fh3Pcglrq3EgqdL9PPJCzFYii1FTUzGa7VpSxFsB6PS1e8x7iPHWmL5BkCgw7Iz%2B5wU6tAEHdMWLGe08smJ8rzDIZJ%2Fdl7vHPXwAhcBpKLcXInlOVDidF%2BNE5kW2S3Ih0Gtou5fIla4qfK4Ta6zqhhZKGEdTpV0t%2BjTNrY5q3C0VFG1Yoq%2B%2FaI8SljyoBD787cx6vXm%2Fj8TptY4EZli%2FjXSU5oA8kT3wkpCaVCY1wnP5lC2xJrTtJMI86MJfUmmX%2Bh0uctfEVN0Tu3ZZR003KK7vbq3bnTpVxpNBkALGO2DXeHN6fH8%2F0pc%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAQ3PHCVTYXSMTN522&Expires=1560252075&Signature=PAr0EefKON5BFfq6iJGY2dC%2F6BE%3D&hash=215a914840f55dd4923aea86e2325d6ba99b091a2cab5abf2fa7d417c5052cf2&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0012365X0300044X&tid=spdf-b6b3f41c-85c3-4378-b500-2b7ae419c08e&sid=81957f618e110747f6380d7016ea9a82bbe5gxrqa&type=client&download=true) (not paywalled)and the references therein.

Briefly, for a finite sequence $(e_1,\ldots, e_N)\in \{\pm 1\}^N$ of length $N,$ they define the *well-distribution measure* of the sequence by
$$
W(e_1,\ldots,e_N)=\max_{a,b,t \in \mathbb{N}} \left| \sum_{j=0}^{t-1} e_{a+jb} \right|
$$
where the maximum is taken over all AP's within 
$\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$.

Another measure they define is the *correlation measure of order* $k$

$$
C_k(e_1,\ldots,e_N)=\max_{M,0\leq d_1<d_2<\ldots<d_k} \left| 
\sum_{n=1}^M e_{n+d_1} e_{n+d_2} \cdots e_{n+d_k} 
\right|
$$
with $M+d_k\leq N.$ They prove that for any sequence,

$$
W(e_1,\ldots,e_N) \leq \sqrt{3 N C_2(e_1,\ldots,e_N)}
$$
while for almost all sequences in $\{\pm 1\}^N$ one has
$$
\sqrt{N} \ll C_2(e_1,\ldots,e_N) \ll \sqrt{N\log N}
$$

They also consider Champerpowne, Thue-Morse, and other sequences, with respect to these measures.

Comment: That's beautiful, thanks @kodlu for this wonderful answer!